# Appropriate way to introduce a hashtag on a web page SEO wise

Tags: seo, html, html5

I want to introduce a hashtag in a site's slider and I know it shoudn't be an anchor tag what's the correct tag for this considering SEO.

[image]

Comment: Why shouldn’t it be an `a` element? What’s the point of the hashtag? Do you expect people to use it? Do you want people to visit it (on Twitter?), do you link this to one of your pages and it’s just a way of phrasing the slogan/title?

Answer (score 1):

A hashtag is just text like anything else. Add it the way you would any other word or sentence and move on.